# How to put text and clickable icons in a Ext.Panel header?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I would like to put text and clickable icons in the headers in my panels, like this:
[image]

I've found some [old hacks from 2008 to do this](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?41156-Buttons-on-panel-header&p=194506), but can imagine that the newer versions of ExtJS allow you to put text and icons in panel headers in a more straightforward way.

**What is the most straight-forward way to put text and clickable icons in a Ext.Panel header?**

## Addendum

thanks @Stefan that worked, here's my solution:

[image]

**Javascript:**

```
var grid_shopping_cart = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
    headerCfg: {
        tag: 'div',
        cls: 'x-panel-header',
        children: [
            { tag: 'div', cls: 'panel_header_main', 'html': 'Shopping Cart' },
            { tag: 'div', cls: 'panel_header_icon1', 'html': '<img src="images/icon_plus.png" />' },
            { tag: 'div', cls: 'panel_header_extra', 'html': 'Order Number: 2837428347' }
        ]
    },
    width: 600,
    height: 390,
    ...
    listeners: {
        'afterrender' : function(p) {
            p.header.on('click', function(e, h) {
                alert('you clicked the plus');
            }, p, {
                delegate: '.panel_header_icon1',
                stopEvent: true
            });
        },
        ...
```

**CSS:**

```
div.panel_header_main {
    text-align: left;
    float: left;
}

div.panel_header_extra {
    text-align: left;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

div.panel_header_icon1 {
    text-align: right;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 3px;
    cursor: hand;
    cursor: pointer;
}

div.panel_header_icon2 {
    text-align: right;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 3px;
    cursor: hand;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Is there a better way to do this now that we're at extjs 4.1.3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you can use the `headerCfg` configuration option of the [Ext.Panel](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.Panel):

```
...,
headerCfg: {
    tag: 'div',
    cls: 'x-panel-header',
    children: [
        { tag: 'div', cls: 'my-title', 'html': 'Shopping Cart' },
        { tag: 'div', cls: 'my-status', 'html': 'Status: on <img src="status.png" />' }
    ]
},
...
```

The clickable behavior must be added in the `afterrender` event for example:

```
function(p) {
    p.header.on('click', function(e, h) {
    }, p, {
        delegate: '.my-status',
        stopEvent: true
    });
}
```

You'll need some css to style the header of course...

Comment: Is there a better way to do this now that we're at extjs 4.1.3?

Comment: @Edward, are you using SASS (compiled CSS) or defining the classes using CSS?  Can you share what you needed to do for those classes?

Answer (score 3):

Even more straightforward seems to be just slapping html into the title tag.

```
title: '<span style="cursor:help" title="' + strTitle + '">' 
    + strTitle + '</span>',
```

After painfully searching up an autoEl and header workaround, this works, at least on 2.2.